# A question on one if and only if relation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be random variables such that $X_2$ and $X_3$ are independent while $X_1,X_2$ are not and $X_1,X_3$ are not as well. Let $f:R\times R\to R$ be some function. Suppose we know that $\exists f_1,f_2$ such that $f(X_1,X_2) = f_1(X_1)+f_2(X_2)$. Then $f(X_1,X_2) - f_1(X_1)$ and $X_3$ are independent.

Can we say the converse, i.e. given that $f(X_1,X_2)-f_1(X_1)$ and $X_3$ are independent, $X_1,X_2$ are not and $X_1,X_3$ are not, for some function $f_1(X_1)$. Then the function $f$ is of the form $f(X_1,X_2) = f_1(X_1)+f_2(X_2)$

Comment: No chance. Assume that $(X_1,X_2)$ is independent of $X_3$. Then all the hypotheses are met and $f$ can be **any** function.

Comment: Good point. Sorry, I forgot to add some conditions.